# Change Color, move and bold text in header table on Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to change text color from table, move the text to center and put it bold text from a table or a graph in qlik sense, like in the following image:

[image]

That can be done without extensions? What is the alternative? any tutorial? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment for the title, at least by using your run-of-the-mill edit mode.

If you have css knowledge, you can make a theme that applies your wanted format onto the title.